# Monotone boolean satisfiability with at most k 1s is NP-Complete

Tags: np-complete, np-hard, satisfiability

I am to prove that monotone boolean formula satisfiability checking when at most k variables are set to 1 is an NP-Complete problem.  Proving that it is in NP is easy, but I'm having difficulty showing that it is in NP-Hard.  I have seen [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11558/prove-np-completeness-of-deciding-satisfiability-of-monotone-boolean-formula), but I would rather not use its solution, as the textbook for the course I am self studying does not present Dominating Sets as an NP-Complete problem.  The NP-Complete problems presented in my book(Dasgupta, Papadimitriou, and Vazirani) are the following: 3SAT, Traveling Salesman, Longest Path, 3D-Matching, Knapsack, Independent Set (related to Dominating Set from what I understand), Vertex Cover, Clique, Integer Linear Programming, Rudrata Path, and Balanced Cut.

From my understanding of the problem, if you restrict the clauses to 2 literals each, then this directly parallels the vertex cover problem, and is thus NP-hard.  I was wondering if there was any way that I could use this fact to say that the unrestricted problem is also NP-Hard.  I intuitively feel that this should work, because the restricted version is a subset of the restricted version, so in at least some cases the problem is NP-hard.  Since you always take the worst case scenario, could you extend this to NP-hardness for the unrestricted problem?  If so, how would I word that (this is for a self study, not to be turned in), in the proper form?  Because my above explanation has a roundabout method of showing the point.

tl;dr Can you prove that something is np-hard by showing that a subproblem is np-hard?  I intuitively feel like you should, but want to confirm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $L'$ be a restriction of $L$, say $L' = L \cap D$. Here $D$ is a restriction on the inputs such as "all clauses have two literals each".

Suppose that $L'$ is NP-hard. Then for every language $M$ in NP, there is a polytime reduction $\varphi$ from $M$ to $L'$ such that $x \in M$ iff $\varphi(x) \in L'$. If $\varphi(x) \in D$ for *all* $x$, then $\varphi(x) \in L'$ iff $\varphi(x) \in L$, and so $\varphi$ is also a reduction from $M$ to $L$.

Usually NP-hardness proofs go by reduction from some specific NP-complete problem $M$. If the polytime reduction $\varphi$ from $M$ to $L'$ showing that $L'$ is NP-hard satisfies the property $\varphi(x) \in D$ for all $x$ (in other words, its range is [contained in] $D$), then the reasoning in the preceding paragraph shows that $\varphi$ also proves that $L$ itself is NP-hard.

For example, in your case $L$ is the set of pairs $\langle \psi,k \rangle$ such that $\psi$ is a monotone Boolean formula that can be satisfies by setting at most $k$ of the literals to TRUE; $D$ is the set of pairs $\langle \psi,k \rangle$ such that $\psi$ is a monotone 2CNF; and $L' = L \cap D$ is the set of pairs $\langle \psi,k \rangle$ such that $\psi$ is a monotone 2CNF that can be satisfied by setting at most $k$ of the literals to TRUE. Any reduction $\varphi$ showing that $L'$ is NP-complete whose range is $D$ also shows that $L$ is NP-complete.

To check that you understand the argument, try to see what goes wrong when we take $L'$ to be, say, 3SAT, and $L$ to be the language of all 3CNFs.

Finally, here is a trick that you can use to emulate SAT in your setting. Suppose that some CNF $\varphi$ has variables $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, some of them possibly appearing negated. Consider $\psi = \varphi' \land (x_1 \lor y_1) \land \cdots \land (x_n \lor y_n)$, where $\varphi'$ results from replacing $\lnot x_i$ by $y_i$. Then $\varphi$ is satisfiable iff $\psi$ is satisfiable by a truth assignment in which at most (or exactly) $n$ variables are TRUE.

Comment: I'm marking your answer as correct, but I have one more question.  On the part where you were emulating SAT by replacing the negated variables.  I don't see how that replacement could work, because it allows both $x_i$ and $y_i$ to be true, which is equivalent to $x_i$ and $\lnot x_i$ both being true which is a logical impossibility?

Comment: @SamadwaraReddy I suggest you reflect more on the issue.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus This is a few years late, I hope it's still ok.
I remembered your answer here and I used your trick in the final paragraph in my exam. Slight variation (3CNF to monotone 3CNF) I got 0 points for that and wanted to ask if possible if you may have a citation, so I may present it? I found it very memorable and easy to do and absolutely valid, which is why I was able to recall it at the exam.

Comment: My answer can function as a citation.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I see, thank you. I found it perfectly valid too. I was just weary of citing internet answers. Thanks though, either way your answer has thought me well and I remembered the proof idea by only reading it once months ago.