# Monotone boolean satisfiability problem : finding minimal solutions

Tags: optimization, satisfiability, planar-graphs

I am very interested in the following questions, which sprang out from the topological study of loops in surfaces and their intersection numbers.

Consider, over a finite set of boolean variables $X$, a [Boolean formula in CNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem) (conjunctive normal form) whose clauses only contain non-negated literals.
Assume the following "planarity & connectedness restrictions": the variables are the vertices of a planar graph whose faces have degree 4
and the variables in any clause must induce a connected subgraph.

For every assignment $a$ of the variables which satisfies the formula, one may consider the following subset of $X$: $T_a = \{x\in X: a(x) \mathrm{\:is\:true}\}$.
A satisfying assignment $a$ will thus be called *minimal* if $T_a$ is minimal with respect to inclusion and *optimal* if $T_a$ has minimal cardinality among all solutions.

**QA**) What is the complexity (NP-complete, P-space-complete, etc.) of the following problems ?

1. Compute the size $|T_a|$ of optimal solutions.
2. Construct an optimal solution.

**QB**) For which positive integers $m \le M$ can one construct such a formula with $m$ optimal solutions and $M$ minimal solutions?

PS : I am rather new to these satisfiability questions, I consulted a few references online (relevant Wikipédia pages, the "Handbook of satisfiability", courses etc) without seeing any mention of this question. There are some papers about "MIN-SAT" and "MAX-SAT" but these address a different question, namely extremize the number of satisfied clauses, whereas i'm interested in extremizing the number of variables.

PPS: According to this cs.stackexchange [thread](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11558/prove-np-completeness-of-deciding-satisfiability-of-monotone-boolean-formula), my problem QA1 is NP-complete when dropping the "planarity & connectedness constraints".

Thanks you for your help,

Comment: @greybeard I am not sure i understand your comment. My questions is not a "homework assignment" if that is what you mean, and all these words are mine so i don't believe any quote is appropriate. 
These questions sprang out from my research about topology of loops in surfaces, and i tried to formulate them in a language suited to this forum. 
If they are of a "standard textbook level" i apologize and would be very happy to have references (i guess that's part of what this forum is about : sharing information to answer precise questions).

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  If you have multiple questions or multiple problems you want to ask about, each can be posted separately in its own post.